# TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int - unable to subtract time data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the total hours worked through with this line of code:

```
df['Hours'] = (df['T1 Finish'] - df['T1 Start']) * 24
```

The data entered for Start and Finish is in the 24hour clock format (example start 13:00, finish 21:00)

I've tried reformatting it and converting with this:

```
df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str))
df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Start'].astype(str))
```

I've also tried:

```
df['T1 Finish'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

df['T1 Start'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
```

But even after doing this, I'm still getting an error but this time the TypeError. Is there any other way I can obtain the number of hours worked from the subtraction of the finish and start times?

I've read up on the documentation around .to_timedelta, but I don't really understand how to apply it to my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substract timedeltas or datetimes and output are timedeltas, which are converted to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), for hours divide by `3600`:

```
df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['T1 Finish'] + ':00')
df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['T1 Start'] + ':00')
```

Or:

```
df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str))
df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Start'].astype(str))
```

For dates use:

```
df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str)).dt.normalize()
df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Start'].astype(str)).dt.normalize()
```

For times:

```
df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str))
df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['T1 Start'].astype(str))
```

---

```
df['Hours'] = (df['T1 Finish'] - df['T1 Start']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much, I used the 2nd option and it worked! When I open the excel file with the calculations, it has changed the Start and Finish times and added Today's date and then the time e.g. 2021-11-19 10:45:00, is there any way I can just keep it as time without the date? Or is that what the first option does?

Comment: @cchev - Answer is edited.

Comment: I meant to have the code return Start and Finish as times only (as it originally was) without the added date of 2021-11-19. But thanks, that's also useful to know!